# как сделать регистрацию в боте дискорд

Tags: discord, discord.py

Как сделать регистрацию в боте дискорд?
Например:
кто-то пишет !регистарция,
пишет имя,
пишет о себе.
И он регистрируется в боте
и потом командой !профиль (будет информация о пользователи). И все данные сохранялись в users.json

Comment: Для начала подумать, как и где сохранять данные

Comment: в users.json сохранять все данные

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Думаю команду вы уже напишите сами

```py
import os
import json

member = ctx.author
data = dict()
data["id"] = member.id
data["name"] = str(member)

def where_json(file_name): # Функция проверки существования json файла
    return os.path.exists(file_name)

def dump(filename, filecontent): # Функция записи json файлов
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(filecontent, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

def load(filename): # Функция загрузки json файлов
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        return json.load(f)

if where_json("users.json"):
    try:
        json_file = load("users.json")
    except:
        json_file = {}
    if member.id not in json_file:
        dump("users.json", data)
else:
    dump("users.json", data)
```

Comment: "member" is not defined - вот такая ошибка получается

Comment: Изучите сначала базовый синтаксис языка, а уже потом следует изучать фреймворки, код работает правильно

Comment: Я уже изучал на базовом уровне питон и фреймворк flask, немного сам сделал бота но некоторые вещи я не знаю как делать

Comment: И в чём тогда проблема?

Comment: Я написал этот код и member подсвечивается жёлтым цветом и написано "member" is not defined

Comment: Изучите базовый синтаксис языка и ошибки

Comment: я понял в чём проблема и теперь всё работает, вот только есть один вопрос как сделать чтобы при команде бот присылал сообщение информации о пользователе

Comment: Если помогло, поставьте галочку, слева от ответа. А на счёт отправки сообщений читайте [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=send#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)